# Optimizing N-queen with openmp c

Tags: c, openmp

I am solving the n Queens problem with OpenMP.

(The original eight queens problem consisted of trying to find a way to place eight queens on a chessboard so that no queen would attack any other queen.

An alternate way of expressing the problem is to place eight “anythings” on an eight by eight grid such that none of them share a common row, column, or diagonal.)

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define MAX_N 16

int check_acceptable(int queen_rows[MAX_N], int n)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
   {
      for (j = i+1; j < n; j++)
      {
         // two queens in the same row => not a solution!
         if (queen_rows[i] == queen_rows[j]) return 0;

         // two queens in the same diagonal => not a solution!
         if (queen_rows[i] - queen_rows[j] == i - j ||
            queen_rows[i] - queen_rows[j] == j - i)
            return 0;
       }
   }

   return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int n;
   int max_iter = 1;

   double start_time, end_time;
   int number_solutions = 0;

   {
       int num_workers;
       int i;

       n = (argc > 1) ? atoi(argv[1]) : 8;
       num_workers = (argc > 2) ? atoi(argv[2]) : 30;

       omp_set_num_threads(num_workers);

       for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
       {
          max_iter *= n;
       }
   }

   start_time = omp_get_wtime();

   int iter;
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (iter = 0; iter < max_iter; iter++)
   {
      int code = iter;
      int i;
      int queen_rows[MAX_N];
      // the index correspond to the queen's number and the queen's column
      // we only generate configurations where there's only one queen per column
      for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
         queen_rows[i] = code % n;

         code /= n;
      }

      if (check_acceptable(queen_rows, n))
      {
        #pragma omp atomic
        number_solutions++;

        #pragma omp critical
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int j;
                for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
                {
                    if (queen_rows[i] == j) printf("|X");
                    else printf("| ");
                }
                printf("|\n");
             }
             printf("\n");
         }
      }
   }

   // get end time
   end_time = omp_get_wtime();

   // print results
   printf("The execution time is %g sec\n", end_time - start_time);
   printf("Number of found solutions is %d\n", number_solutions);

   return 0;
}
```

What do I do to optimize this code? What are the things making the code slow, cache or what?

Comment: I am not specifically very familiar with openmp, but check for code divergence, some of the threads are more loaded then the others which is probably difficult in this particular problem to perfectly balance among the threads.

Comment: With values like `n=16`, `int max_iter`  likely overflows in `for (i = 0; i < n; i++)     {         max_iter *= n;     }`.  Suggest `long long`.

Answer (score 1):

Parallelizing NQueens is typical exercise when learning recursive and/or task parallelism (which is not what you actually used). To parallelize NQueens use back-tracking algorithm; backtracking algorithm is perfectly described in many places:

- DrDobbs article: http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/print?articleId=214303519
- See also *answer* for this question: [Optimizing N-queen with openmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078635/optimizing-n-queen-with-openmp)